# Unable login with FBLogin view on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login

I've created Facebook app using Facebook login flow from the developer page step by step. Login works great. My problem is that this is not working on iPhone 5 or 5s.

I have tried to check on 6 different iPhones 5 and it works only on one of them. Once I've clicked on "login" I get alert with the message `the app would like to access to you basic info` I get the `user cancel login` error once I click on "ok" or "don't allow" in the alert. and nothing happens. any idea what could be the problem? thank you

[image: iphone 5 and 5s problem]

[image: login and errors]

[image: this is how its open in all devices accept from iPhone 5 and 5s.]

Comment: Have you ever clicked on Don't Allow, any time using this app?

Comment: hi, yes i try, but same error..it send me to the error "user cancelled login". same on both buttons.

Comment: Are you using the simulator or running on a real iphone? If you are on iphone, go to Configurations -> Facebook, is your app listed there?

Comment: on simulator it works. when i use the iPhone 5 or 5s it dosnt work, and yes i can see the Facebook app in settings.

Comment: and today it worked on 1 iPhone from 4 that i try.. same preferences

Comment: In the facebook settings menu, it says your app is allowed?

Comment: yes. i try so many ways..do you know about native login? someone told me i should try that.

Comment: First, could you please post the code that handles the facebook login, here? Second, sorry for asking so many questions, but managing facebookSDK is not as trivial as it should, and there a lot of things that could be wrong here, so i started with the most basic. For example, you are using ios native login which works like this: if the user EVER click on 'Don't allow', the only way he could go back and log in, is if he goes to facebook settings and allow the app manually. So, i highly recommend that you bypass ios facebook native login and go for plain facebook native login.

Comment: i added the pic of the code. for now i use only the plain Facebook login and it works on all devices accept iPhone 5 and 5s...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46385/discussion-between-user3136102-and-xicocaio)

Comment: The button picture shows how it works on other devices just not on iPhone 5 or 5s.

Comment: I am on chat if you wanna talk there

Comment: HI. i use the FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView that you told me about... thank you so much for your help.. this is the page with the information. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial#dialogs

Comment: I am on chat if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using FBLoginView, try using FBSession like this:

```
// no action can be done on facebook if there is no session on open state 
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) { 
   FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_birthday"]]; 
   [FBSession setActiveSession:session]; 

   // Here this behavior garantees that the iOS Login Dialog is not shown, because it was causing some login issues 
   // The fallback flow will be: 1- Facebook App Native Login Dialog; 2- Facebook App Web Login Dialog; 3- Mobile Safari Login Dialog 
   [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView 
                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                  if(error) { // your code here }
                                  else { // your code here }
                             }}];
```